# FB.init() callback stopped been called

Tags: facebook, actionscript-3, facebook-graph-api

I know that there are similar question, but I think that my situation might be different.

I have two facebook applications. One is for develop - it works in sandbox mode and works with localhost. The other one is for production, with the sandbox mode off and an active ssl.
I haven't used develop app for some time, and now I've found that FB.init() is not called anymore. However, in Google Chrome browser everything works fine, and production server works in all browsers. What can be the reason of this problem? Did Facebook got some king of update or something like that? Maybe it stopped to work because develop app needs SSL too?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Took me some time, but I figured it out. Now to use your develop non ssl applications on facebook, first you have to go into Security tab in facebook account settings and set Secure Browsing to disabled.
What I can't understand, why I haven't got any notification from facebook about this issue? If there was some kind of notification, then it was too hidden.